# Extract Links from a sitemap(xml)

Tags: url, xml, extract, sitemap

Lets say I have a `sitemap.xml` file with this data:

```
<url>
<loc>http://domain.com/pag1</loc>
<lastmod>2012-08-25</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://domain.com/pag2</loc>
<lastmod>2012-08-25</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://domain.com/pag3</loc>
<lastmod>2012-08-25</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```

I want to extract all the locations from it (data between `<loc>` and `</loc>`).

Sample output be like:

```
http://domain.com/pag1
http://domain.com/pag2
http://domain.com/pag3
```

How to do this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate X64 / Windows 8 Pro X64 or Ubuntu 12.04 Linux.

Comment: Nice setup. Using Terminal on the Ubuntu box, [my answer below](http://superuser.com/a/466874/152250) will get you what you need.

Comment: You can also use any text editor like SublimeText2 which can use regexp, you can get all data with it, or you can use python see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python script here

This script get any links started with *http*

```
import re

f = open('sitemap.xml','r')
res = f.readlines()
for d in res:
    data = re.findall('>(http:\/\/.+)<',d)
    for i in data:
        print i
```

And in your case next script find all data wraped in  tags

```
import re

f = open('sitemap.xml','r')
res = f.readlines()
for d in res:
    data = re.findall('<loc>(http:\/\/.+)<\/loc>',d)
    for i in data:
        print i
```

[Here](http://regex101.com/) nice tool to play with regexp if you not familiar with it.

if you need to load remote file you can use next code

```
import urllib2 as ur
import re

f = ur.urlopen(u'http://server.com/sitemap.xml')
res = f.readlines()
for d in res:
  data = re.findall('<loc>(http:\/\/.+)<\/loc>',d)
  for i in data:
    print i
```

Comment: How to load a remote file like `http://server.com/sitemap.xml`. I am not so known to Python

Comment: you mean load with python?

Comment: Yup, Like you have used `f = open('sitemap.xml','r')` to open the file, How to open a remote file on http server?

Comment: i update my post, you need to use urllib2 module

Comment: Shows error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findall'`

Comment: do you import re module?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4660/discussion-between-ishikawa-yoshi-and-akshat-mittal)

Comment: Very good answer! A reminder that if your links are in HTTPS, change *http* to *https* in the code).

Answer (score 9):

If you're on a Linux box or something with the [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) tool, you can just run:

> grep -Po 'http(s?)://[^ \"()\<>]*' sitemap.xml

Comment: This worked but with a lot of mistakes (Incomplete URL's).

Comment: Weird, I just ran this over [Google's sitemap.xml file](http://www.google.com/sitemap.xml) and didn't see any issues. Which ones did it miss?

Comment: This missed many url's that contained "?" and "+".

Comment: Thank you. For anybody wants to save to file `grep -Po 'http(s?)://[^ \"()\<>]*' sitemap.xml > links.txt`

Comment: +1 This is actually a very simple but powerful solution.

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished by a single sed command, which seems to be more solid than the grep solution:

```
sed '/<loc>/!d; s/[[:space:]]*<loc>\(.*\)<\/loc>/\1/' inputfile > outputfile
```

*(found at: [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5402475))*

Comment: Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: tried it as  sed '/<loc>/!d; s/[[:space:]]*<loc>\(.*\)<\/loc>/\1/' sitemap.xml > links.txt but it outputs the same xml content. it worked with the above grep command but I am trying to figure out why it did not work

Comment: I think it's because you did not escape the () with \( and \).

Answer (score 1):

Using `XSLT`, you can render it out with `XPath`

```
/url/loc
```

Comment: Could you maybe expand your answer and show the XSLT instructions and the XPath queries needed?

Comment: @slhck Exactly what I wanted to say,The answer should be more explainatory.

Comment: I read a few more about this and got this working at last. Upvoting but not a really good answer to be choosen.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:s="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="s:url">
    <xsl:value-of select="s:loc" />
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For years i've been using regex etc. for this but XSLT is so cool in this case :) For complete noobs in XSLT (like me) it'd be nice to add that only thing you have to do is: save this code as stylesheet.xsl and add a row to your xml document with link to stylesheet <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" version="1.0" href="stylesheet.xsl"?> Then open your xml in browser (it won't work when opening as local file, you have to get it via http)

Answer (score 0):

You can open your `sitemap.xml` file in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Then in the menu Search → Replace (CTRL+H) specify:

Find what: `</loc>.*?<loc>`

Replace with: `\r\n`

Set Search mode to [Regular Expression](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/index.html#regular-expressions)

and then click `Replace All` button.

Additionally you can sort the links via the Menu `Edit → Line Operations → Sort Lines in Ascending Order`